# How to display a custom button?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I am using `ListView` in web user control to display data from different tables in survey format in which user have to give answer i.e. either choosing from multiple options or give his own opinion in `TextBox`, i want to add a custom button in `ListView`'s data pager which will work as a submit button?

I have no idea how to do it? Any one's help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add a button per line or just one at the bottom?

Comment: but i want to handle it through ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the `ListView` pager inside the `ListView` `LayoutTemplate`:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server" id=" table1">
          <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder">
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- This is the pager. Define all necessary markup here. -->
        <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="DataPager" PageSize="5">
            <Fields>
                <asp:TemplatePagerField>              
                    <PagerTemplate>
                        <!-- Pager template goes here -->
                    </PagerTemplate>
                </asp:TemplatePagerField>
            </Fields>
        </asp:DataPager>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: but where is the custom button? as per my knowledge you can only add NEXT, PREVIOUS, BACK button in data pager in Fields tag? but how to add a custom button which can be used as a Submit button

Comment: @Sheery You can have a templatepagerfiled. I am updating the answer with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Konstantin D - Infragistics, just one more thing i have added a button btn_Submit in <PagerTemplate> but unable to find it's Click event, kindly guide me how to add click event of btn_Submit?

Comment: @Sheery Is this client click or server click?

Comment: it is Client Click, but will insert values into the database on Click Event.

Comment: @Sheery The easiest would be to provide the event handler in markup: <input type="submit" onclientclick="eventHandler(this)" />

Comment: Thanks Konstantin D - Infragistics .

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

```
 protected void CurrentRowTextBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, 
        EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;
        DataPager pager = 
            (DataPager)EmployeesListView.FindControl("EmployeesDataPager");
        pager.SetPageProperties(Convert.ToInt32(t.Text) - 1, 
             pager.PageSize, true);
    }
```